# After exiting the server can't reconnect. Receive error "ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host"

Tags: ssh

I connect to my server fine. But then when I exit I cannot immediately connect back in. And I receive this error:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Only after about an hour+ I am able to reconnect.
Any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it? This does not happen on any other of my servers that I exit from and then reconnect to..

Here is the snippet of my terminal window that shows my connection and then after exiting the error message..

```
devenv@DevEnv0:~$ ssh root@104.---.1-4.91
Last failed login: Thu Apr 27 05:55:02 UTC 2017 from 180.---.1--.83 on ssh:notty
There were 134 failed login attempts since the last successful login.
Last login: Wed Apr 26 14:37:34 2017 from ppp-46--------156.wildpark.net
[root@secure ~]# exit
logout
Connection to 104.---.1-4.91 closed.
devenv@DevEnv0:~$ ssh root@104.---.1-4.91
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
devenv@DevEnv0:~$ ssh root@104.---.1-4.91
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
devenv@DevEnv0:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the server log. It will tell you the reason for the rejection (if not, set higher log level).

This is most probably caused by wrongly configured `fail2ban` or similar service, which is issuing a temporary ban for your IP address in `tcp_wrappers`. But without more information, it is just a 90% guess.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry - I'm a bit new to Linux and ssh. How do I check my server log if I can't log in right now?